# How can I use fields_for to update a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fields-for

I am making a quiz, and I have a `Survey` Model, `Question` Model and a `Choice` model
I am looping over all of the questions and showing the choices for that question
there is also a column on the choices table for the answer they had given, which is what I am trying to update.

Here is my code.

SurveyController

```
def show
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
end
```

Survey Model

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :questions
end
```

Question Model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :question
  has_many :choices
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

Choice Model

```
class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Survey Show View

```
<div class="modal-wrap">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <% @survey.questions.size.times do %>
      <span></span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-bodies">
    <%= form_for @survey do |form| %>
      <% @survey.questions.each.with_index(1) do |question, index| %>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="title">Question <%= index %></div>
            <div class="description"><%= question.question %></div>
              <%= form.fields_for :choices, question.choices do |choice_fields| %>
                <%= choice_fields.text_field :name %>
              <% end %>
              <div class="text-center">
                <div class="button">Next</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

I can't get the form_for to work properly, can someone help me get this to work please?

Comment: shouldn't it be form.fields_for ... ?

Comment: yes, sorry I have corrected it, it's still not right though

Comment: I think your question Model also should have accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices and you should permit the params in your Questions controller for :choices.